# Dbt labs access remote Postgres DB server using db link

Tags: postgresql, dbt

I am new to DBT. I understand that DBT is used for transforming data once the raw data is available in your DWH. However I was trying to see if anyone has used DBT to do an initial select/import of data into staging tables from a remote database server using DB link in a select statement where both the staging database server and the remote database server are Postgres databases.
Also in my case the data volume isn’t much.

Comment: And what is the real question? I don't think you're looking for just a Yes or No.

Comment: Sure, since DBT isn't an EL tool, I was trying to find if its possible to use DB link to select data from 1 database server and load it into staging table in another database server. If possible I was also looking for any pointers/documentation/link on how to set it up since I didn't find any reference online.  If not, I can look for alternate means to port the data before I can start using DBT to transform it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do some testing and looks like this is doable.
Below was the set-up:

1. The profiles.yml file was pointing to target DB server.
2. Below was the query used in the model targetTable.sql file.

```
{{ config(materialized='table') }}

SELECT i.col1,
        i.col2
        FROM dblink('dbname=sourceDBName port=portNo hostaddr=sourceHostName user=userID password=****', 
                                'SELECT 
                                a.col1, 
                                a.col2
                                from 
                                (SELECT 
                                    col1,col2
                                 FROM 
                                    public.tableName) a
                                ') 
                i (col1 integer, col2 varchar(20))
```